# how to publish c++ qt project in ubuntu app store

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, commercial

I doing a c++ qt5 commercial app for publishing in ubuntu app store, I installed ubuntu sdk to develop and publish it. My surprise was there is no button for publish it in ubuntu sdk, so I'm ask how to put my app in ubuntu app store ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/get-started/). Its the official Ubuntu web page for developers.

Comment: What I want to know is if I need to pack it myself to deb package or pack the source code in tar gz and then upload it and wait that the packagers of ubuntu pack it.

Answer (score 0):

They want you to submit it in a tarball. That way a reviewer can check the source code to make sure it compiles correctly into binary. I believe they also do minor checks for grammar and profanity.

Comment: the tarball is the project in source code ?

Comment: Yes, with make file and all... at least according to everything I have read about it thus far. Unfortunately everything I have found is pretty vague and seems to be geared towards mobile development rather than desktop (maybe mobile devs know something I don't O.o).
  _Also, please pardon any grammatical errors, I've has a few beers tonight lol._